# Selenium Python: a better way to do this

Tags: selenium, webdriver

A better cleaner way to achieve this is appreciated guys...

```
import random<br>
import time<br>
from selenium import webdriver<br>
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys<br>

randomNumber = random.randint(1, 3)<br>
randomNumber1 = random.randint(1, 3)<br>
randomNumber2 = random.randint(1, 3)<br>
randomNumber3 = random.randint(1, 3)<br>
randomNumber4 = random.randint(1, 3)<br>
randomNumber5 = random.randint(1, 3)<br>
randomNumber6 = random.randint(1, 3)<br>
randomNumber7 = random.randint(1, 3)<br>
randomNumber8 = random.randint(1, 3)<br>
randomNumber9 = random.randint(1, 3)<br>
randomNumber10 = random.randint(1, 3)<br>



driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[" + str(randomNumber) + "]/a/span").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[" + str(randomNumber2) + "]/a/span").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[" + str(randomNumber3) + "]/a/span").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[3]/div[" + str(randomNumber4) + "]/a/span").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[5]/div[3]/div[" + str(randomNumber5) + "]/a/span").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[7]/div[1]/div[3]/div[" + str(randomNumber6) + "]/a/span").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div[3]/div[" + str(randomNumber7) + "]/a/span").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[7]/div[3]/div[3]/div[" + str(randomNumber8) + "]/a/span").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[7]/div[4]/div[3]/div[" + str(randomNumber9) + "]/a/span").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[7]/div[5]/div[3]/div[" + str(randomNumber10) + "]/a/span").click()
```

Comment: Do you need to keep the random values?

Comment: I you want to improve the code, you should take a look into [the code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
numbers = [random.randint(1,3) for x in range(11)] #Generates a list of 10 random numbers between 1 and 3

for number in numbers: #Loops through the list of random numbers generated
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[" + str(number) + "]/a/span").click() #Clicks on the respective xpath of each number
```